# Help with EF Code first connection string

Tags: entity-framework, repository, repository-pattern, unit-of-work

Im trying to implement a UnitofWork pattern using [this Scott Allen tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff714955.aspx)

My current SqlUnitOfWork is the folowing

```
public class SqlUnitOfWork : IUnitOfWork {

        public SqlUnitOfWork() {
            var connectionString =
                ConfigurationManager
                    .ConnectionStrings[ConnectionStringName]
                    .ConnectionString;

            _context = new ObjectContext(connectionString);
            _context.ContextOptions.LazyLoadingEnabled = true;
        }

        public IRepository<PhysicalTest> PhysicalTests
        {
            get {
                if (_physicalTests == null)
                {
                    _physicalTests = new SqlRepository<PhysicalTest>(_context);
                }
                return _physicalTests;
            }
        }

        public IRepository<EHR> EHRs
        {
            get
            {
                if (_EHRs == null)
                {
                    _EHRs = new SqlRepository<EHR>(_context);
                }
                return _EHRs;
            }
        }



        public void Commit() {
            _context.SaveChanges();
        }

        SqlRepository<PhysicalTest> _physicalTests = null;
        SqlRepository<EHR> _EHRs = null;

        readonly ObjectContext _context;
        const string ConnectionStringName = "default";
    }
```

and my current connection string is the following

```
<add name="default" connectionString="data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=SSPI;MultipleActiveResultSets=True; initial catalog=MyAppDB" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

It's also worth pointing out that my controllers that are using controllers that were created with mvcscaffolding work fine but the unit of work (which for some reason needs a connectrion string as parameter instead of just using MyAppDBContext() instance) doesnt work.

The error I get when I try to invoke an action inside a controllr with the following code:

```
public class PhysicalTestsController : Controller
    {
        private IUnitOfWork unitOfWork;
        private IRepository<EHR> ehrRepository;


        public PhysicalTestsController(IUnitOfWork unit)
        {
            unitOfWork = unit;
            ehrRepository = unitOfWork.EHRs;
        }


        public ActionResult Index(int ehrId, int? page)
        {
            EHR ehr = ehrRepository.FindById(ehrId);
            if (ehr.UserName != User.Identity.Name)
                return View("Invalid Owner");
            const int pageSize = 5;
            var physicaltests = ehr.PhysicalTests.OrderByDescending(test => test.CreationDate);
            List<PhysicalTestListItem> physicalTestsVM = new List<PhysicalTestListItem>();
            Mapper.Map(physicaltests, physicalTestsVM);
            var paginatedTests = new PaginatedList<PhysicalTestListItem>(physicalTestsVM, page ?? 0, pageSize);
            return View(paginatedTests);
        }
}
```

is  this one

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have changed my SqlRepository to:

```
public class SqlRepository<T> : IRepository<T>
                                    where T : class, IEntity {

        internal SummumnetDB context;
        internal DbSet<T> _objectSet;

        public SqlRepository(SummumnetDB context)
        {
            this.context = context;
            this._objectSet = context.Set<T>();
        }

..... rest of my methods here

}
```

and

my SqlUnitofWork to

```
public class SqlUnitOfWork : IUnitOfWork {

        private SummumnetDB _context = new SummumnetDB();

        public IRepository<PhysicalTest> PhysicalTests
        {
            get {
                if (_physicalTests == null)
                {
                    _physicalTests = new SqlRepository<PhysicalTest>(_context);
                }
                return _physicalTests;
            }
        }..... rest of code here
```

please correct me if this modifications are not appropriate or break one of these patterns

Answer (score -1):

You are using `ObjectContext` not `DbContext`. `ObjectContext` uses `EntityConnection` and its `System.Data.EntityClient` provider. It's connection string has [different format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entityclient.entityconnection.connectionstring.aspx).

Comment: I appreciate your answer.... would you mind taking a look at my provided answer??...  Im just trying to figure out the best approach to implementing the unit of work pattern...I guess my question should have been clearer.. im still not sure if I should keep the code I provided in my question and just change the connectionstring or use the code in my answer which uses DbContext....