# Keyword not supported: 'data source'.: EF code-first using ObjectContext and LocalDB

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, code-first, localdb

I am getting a "keyword not supported error" when I try to connect to a LocalDB database using ObjectContext.

This is my connection string:

```
<add name="connStr" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=proj1db;Integrated Security=True" />
```

and this is the code that tries to create an instance of the ObjectContext:

```
var connectionString = ConfigurationManager
                .ConnectionStrings["connStr"]
                .ConnectionString;
ObjectContext _context = new ObjectContext(connectionString);
```

The last line throws System.ArgumentException: Keyword not supported: 'data source'.

I am using Visual Studio 2012 for Web and targeting .NET Framework 4.5. I have LocalDB installed on my machine.

If I use DbContext instead it works:

```
public class proj1dbContext: DbContext
{
    public proj1dbContext() : base("name=connStr")
    ...
```

It seems that this is a similar question
[Help with EF Code first connection string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6916785/help-with-ef-code-first-connection-string)
but unfortunately it does not give a definitive answer to why instantiating ObjectContext throws that error.

Any help is appreaciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ObjectContext` takes an EF connection string (with `Metadata` and `Provider Connection String` keywords), not a provider-specific connection string.

You can't use ObjectContext with Code-First; ObjectContext requires the metadata XML files.

Comment: BTW, you can access object context via DBContext.                   var _adapter = (IObjectContextAdapter)Context;
            _ObjectContext = _adapter.ObjectContext;

Comment: @phil soady This way it won't, because of connection string differences between Code first and Designer/Database first.